# Exist smooth function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow [0,1] $ with $f(0)=1, f(1)=0$ a function differential such that exist $f^n(0)$, $f^n(1)$ for all $1 \leq n $  and they are equal to $0$ ($f^n$ is the $n$-th derivative ).

Can be $f([0,1])$ a smooth function?

I try moldering the functions like the $\sin, \cos$ or the exponentional but I don´t find a solution, maybe I need more advanced math topics to solve it, still I would like to know how they would do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These can be constructed using [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Define
$$\phi(x)=\cases{e^{-1/x}&if $x>0$,\\0&if $x\leq 0$.}$$
Then $\phi$ is smooth and all derivatives vanish at $0$.
Now set
$$\psi(x)=\phi(x)\phi(1-x).$$
Then $\psi$ is smooth, all derivatives are zero at $0$ and $1$,
$\psi(x)>0$ on $(0,1)$ and $\psi$ is zero elsewhere. Define
$$\chi(x)=\int_0^x\psi(t)\,dt.$$
Then $\chi$ is smooth, increasing, zero for $x\le0$ and a positive constant
for $x\ge1$.
Finally define,
$$f(x)=1-\frac{\chi(x)}{\chi(1)}.$$
Then $f$ does what you want.

Comment: @TravisWillse corrected, I hope!

Comment: a question, $\phi$ is not  defined in x negative or is $0$?

Comment: @FrancoGómez I made a quick edit to the answer - this function is usually defined to be $0$ for all $x\leq 0$.